# Отобразить отдельные столбцы в dataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Через oledb загружаю данные с exel. В dataGridView нужны только отдельные столбцы. Подскажите пожалуйста, как их вывести.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt// отображает  всю БД
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Columns[0] // ничего не отображает
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать после привязки скрыть ненужные столбцы с помощью [`Visible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.visible.aspx):

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
//и т.д.
```

возможно, будет удобнее обращаться к столбцам по имени:

```
//Скрываем все
foreach(DataGridViewColumn column : dataGridView1.Columns)
    column.Visible = false;

//показываем нужное
var visibleColumnNames = new [] {"Column1", "Column2", ...};
foreach(var name : visibleColumnNames)
    dataGridView1.Columns[name].Visible = true;
```

Альтернативный вариант: удалить столбцы из источника данных. Если это `DataTable`, то с помощью [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcdez2aw.aspx):

```
dt.Columns.Remove("Column1");
dt.Columns.Remove("Column2");
...
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Ваш код

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Columns[0]
```

не сработает, т.к. сам по себе столбец корректным источником данных не является.